# how to invoke angular controller if you dont have user interaction?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that i want to use as a listener for events coming from external api's, this controller does not have view so there is no user interaction. How can i invoke controller itself without interacting with another controller ? is it possible to achieve this task in angular ?

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp')
  .controller('CamundaCtrl', function ($scope,BpmnEngine) {
    console.log("test camunda controller");
        BpmnEngine.getCamunda().then(function(response){
          console.log("INSIDE CAMUNDA CTRL Events", response);
          var fetchResponse = response.data;
          var taskId = fetchResponse[0].id;
          var workerId = fetchResponse[0].workerId;
         // completeProcess(taskId,workerId);

        });
})
```

Comment: you should switch to a service.  And register your service when you need it

Comment: put more context to your need. i mean, describe a little more the use-case to understand.

Comment: imagine an scenario, the first think in mind is you want something like how works notifications. am i correct?

Comment: Controllers don't exist when not needed in view so whole idea doesn't make sense